# Is an accurate clock really required to participate in the Ethereum network?

Tags: documentation, p2p

The Ethereum documentation states:

https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/network/connecting-to-the-network.rst#static-nodes-trusted-nodes-and-boot-nodes

> "An accurate clock is required to participate in the Ethereum network.
>   Check your OS for how to resync your clock (example sudo ntpdate -s
>   time.nist.gov) because even 12 seconds too fast can lead to 0 peers."

Is this accurate clock requirement actually enforced? I have tested connecting with geth using a clock one day behind the NTP provided time and geth appears to be able to connect to other peers. I was expecting the other nodes to automatically disconnect if the accurate clock requirement was enforced.

Here is the geth version I am using:

```
$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.6.0-unstable
Git Commit: cc303017c3f145441e583b5bb10ee3070b44cc50
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.8
OS: darwin
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8/libexec
```